# Uploading multiple files from different inputs using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have two different file inputs and multiple textual/select inputs, that I'd like to upload to a PHP file using Ajax. The file inputs are meant to send images, and because they are two specific images that I'd like to identify by the name of the input, I do not want to use `<input type="file" multiple>`.

Currently I have the following (names have been changed to keep it simple):

```
<input type="file" name="file1">
<input type="file" name="file2">
<textarea name="text1"></textarea>
<button>Submit</button>
```

What I have tried is to push both to a variable once the change event of the file input gets fired, followed by the button press triggering the upload using Ajax.

```
$('input[type="file"][name="file1"]').on('change', prepareUpload);
$('input[type="file"][name="file2"]').on('change', prepareUpload);

files = new Array;

function prepareUpload(event){
    files.push(event.target.files);
}

$('button').on('click', uploadFiles);

function uploadFiles(event){

    $('#uploadInfo').html('Uploading...');
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value){
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    data.append('text1', $('textarea[name="text1"]').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(result){
            //do stuff
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

But this seems to do nothing. Is it even possible to append two image inputs to the same request using Ajax, or am I better off trying to put it in two different requests?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a solution to your problem but a comment: You have two files with the same name in your HTML. This will not work. I believe it is just a typo, but it may be in your code also.

Comment: Ah thanks, it's not in my HTML, as I changed all names to make it a bit more simple for other possible use cases and others maybe having the same question :)

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: None, ajax only fires the error function as it isn't getting json back from my PHP file. But the PHP file is getting an empty request.

Comment: how do you know its getting an empty request?

Comment: I added loggers to the file to log all post and get requests to a database, which returned nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target.files` is a array, so you need the first file in the array

```
function prepareUpload(event){
    files.push(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this made it a little more clear for me. Do the new files get prepended or appended to the array? (is it fair to continuously use `event.target.files[0]` for every file or do I need to increment the 0?)

Comment: you have multiple inputs with one file each so you will always have `event.target.files[0]`